# How to scrape text in title attribute using beautiful soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, data-science

I am scraping this website using beautiful soup and I need to get the product name completely. 
When I use the h2 tag, I end up getting names such as "NIVEA Soft Light Moisturizing Cream Berry Blossom Fragrance ...".

I don't want these dots at the end, just the complete name.
Here is my code snippet for scraping the data:

```
div_soup=data_soup.findAll('div',{'class':'product-list-box card desktop-cart'})

table_rows=[]
for div in div_soup:
   current_row=[]
   product_name=div.findAll('h2',{})
   product_price=div.findAll('span',{'class':'post-card__content-price-offer'})
   for idx,data in enumerate(product_name):
       current_row.append(data.text)
   for idx,data in enumerate(product_price):
       current_row.append(data.text)
   table_rows.append(current_row)
```

I can't figure out the appropriate tag to use and also if I should pass something in the dictionary.

URL of the website I am scraping: https://www.nykaa.com/skin/moisturizers/face-moisturizer-day-cream/c/8394?root=nav_3

Answer (score 1):

`for idx,data in enumerate(product_name):
    if data.get('title') is not None:
        current_row.append(data['title'])`

Should do what you want

Also might be best to refactor your code as

`product_name=div.find('h2', {'title': True).get('title')`

So you will just look for a h2 tag with title attribute and you can avoid the for loop